# How to control all GameObjects in array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I have a generator which generate a ball every time I press (1) ,
each ball will be stored in Array of **Gameobjects** called "**targetBall**" , I have an **AI player** which repels the ball with **Move()** method, but the problem is the AI player see only the first ball in array which is ball [0] as shown in code , how I can make the AI player see all the generated ball (infinite balls) , I tried to use for loop but I didn't make it **(note : every thing worked perfect)**

```
void Move()
    {
        targetBall = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("HokeyBall");

            if (targetBall[0].GetComponent<HokyBall>().ballDirection == Vector3.right)
            {
                ballPos = targetBall[0].transform.localPosition;

                if (transform.localPosition.x < Lboundry && ballPos.x > transform.localPosition.x)
                {
                    transform.localPosition += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                }
                if (transform.localPosition.x < Lboundry && ballPos.x < transform.localPosition.x)
                {
                    transform.localPosition += new Vector3(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                }
            }
}
```

and this is my attempt to find each ball generated using for loop , and give me error (cant convert "int" to "GameObject)

```
void Move()
        {
            targetBall = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("HokeyBall");

foreach (GameObject i in targetball)
{
    
                if (targetBall[i].GetComponent<HokyBall>().ballDirection == Vector3.right)
                {
                    ballPos = targetBall[i].transform.localPosition;
    
                    if (transform.localPosition.x < Lboundry && ballPos.x > transform.localPosition.x)
                    {
                        transform.localPosition += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                    }
                    if (transform.localPosition.x < Lboundry && ballPos.x < transform.localPosition.x)
                    {
                        transform.localPosition += new Vector3(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Show your attempt at a loop and explain the issue with that code

Comment: I Add it now thanks

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, `i` is already your `GameObject`, so `targetBall[i]` makes no sense. Replace all those with just `i` (and give it a better name than that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` returns object from the collection, so you don't have access to that collection.

Foreach way -

```
    void Move()
    {
        targetBall = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("HokeyBall");
        foreach (GameObject go in targetball)
        {
            if (go.GetComponent<HokyBall>().ballDirection == Vector3.right)
            {
                ballPos = go.transform.localPosition;
                if (transform.localPosition.x < Lboundry && ballPos.x > transform.localPosition.x)
                {
                    transform.localPosition += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                }

                if (transform.localPosition.x < Lboundry && ballPos.x < transform.localPosition.x)
                {
                    transform.localPosition += new Vector3(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For loop -

```
    void Move()
    {
        targetBall = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("HokeyBall");
        for (int i = 0; i < targetBall.Length; i++)
        {
            if (targetBall[i].GetComponent<HokyBall>().ballDirection == Vector3.right)
            {
                ballPos = targetBall[i].transform.localPosition;
                if (transform.localPosition.x < Lboundry && ballPos.x > transform.localPosition.x)
                {
                    transform.localPosition += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                }

                if (transform.localPosition.x < Lboundry && ballPos.x < transform.localPosition.x)
                {
                    transform.localPosition += new Vector3(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```